# Jacobian Determinant of Polar-Coordinate Transformation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider a Euclidean space of $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ ($n\geq3$) dimensions. The coordinates of any vector can be defined in terms of polar coordinates as follows (this example appears in Folland, 1999):
\begin{align*}
x_1=&\,r\cos\phi_1,\\
x_2=&\,r\sin\phi_1\cos\phi_2,\\
\vdots&\\
x_k=&\,r\left(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\sin\phi_j\right)\cos\phi_k,\\
\vdots&\\
x_{n-1}=&\,r\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n-2}\sin\phi_j\right)\cos\theta,\\
x_{n}=&\,r\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n-2}\sin\phi_j\right)\sin\theta,
\end{align*}
where $(r,(\phi_j)_{j=1}^{n-2},\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Now, the Jacobian determinant corresponding to this transformation is claimed to be given as follows:
\begin{align*}
\det\left(\frac{\partial (x_j)_{j=1}^n}{\partial(r,(\phi_j)_{j=1}^{n-2},\theta)}\right)=r^{n-1}\prod_{j=1}^{n-2}\sin^{n-j-1}\phi_j.
\end{align*}

While this result is “standard,” I have had a hard time proving it. Technically, the problem is that the Jacobian matrix of
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial (x_j)_{j=1}^n}{\partial(r,(\phi_j)_{j=1}^{n-2},\theta)}
\end{align*}
is a Hessenberg matrix: that is, it is “almost triangular,” but there is one extra diagonal set of nonzero elements just above the main diagonal. This makes computing the determinant directly extremely tedious. I tried induction and the Laplace expansion, too, to little avail.

Are any of you familiar with the canonical proof of this result, or any standard reference? Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, you may notice that the determinant is the product of the lengths of the partial derivatives.

The "trick" is that the partial derivatives are orthogonal to each other. If one doesn't see it abstractly, consider

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial\phi_j} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\\
-c\sin\phi_j\\c\cos\phi_j\cos\phi_{j+1}\\c\cos\phi_j\sin\phi_{j+1}\cos\phi_{j+2}\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}$$

where the $c$ is $r$ times the product of the $\sin\phi_i$ for $i < j$. If you look at the corresponding entries of $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi_k}$ for $k < j$, you find

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial\phi_j} = \begin{pmatrix}\ast\\\vdots\\\ast\\
c'\cos\phi_j\\c'\sin\phi_j\cos\phi_{j+1}\\c'\sin\phi_j\sin\phi_{j+1}\cos\phi_{j+2}\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}$$

where the $c'$ contains a factor $\cos \phi_k$ instead of $\sin \phi_k$, and everything after the $\phi_j$ stuff is the same as for $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi_j}$ and in effect the inner product reduces to

$$cc'\left(-\sin\phi_j\cos\phi_j + \cos\phi_j\sin\phi_j(\cos^2\phi_{j+1} + \sin^2\phi_{j+1}(\cos^2\phi_{j+2} + \sin^2\phi_{j+2}(...))))\right) = 0.$$

The case of $\langle \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\mid \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi_j}\rangle$ is analogous. (Name $\theta = \phi_{n-1}$ for uniformity.)

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has been extremely helpful. Just one small addendum to the question: The product of the lengths gives only the absolute value of the determinant, but its sign may remain indefinite using your method. At any rate, this is not important, since relabeling the indices may change the sign anyway and, in addition, only the absolute value of the determinant is needed for the famous change-of-variables formula for which this result is necessary.

Comment: To sum up, your method proves the following:
\begin{align*}
\left|\det\left(\frac{\partial (x_j)_{j=1}^n}{\partial (r,(\phi_j)_{j=1}^{n-2},\theta)}\right)\right|=|r|^{n-1} \prod_{j=1}^{n-2}|\sin \phi_{j}|^{n-j-1}.
\end{align*}
Thank you again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I kept thinking about this problem, because it bugged me that we only had an expression for the absolutely value (I know, I'm a little OCPD). Actually, if the order of the variables is as I reported them, then the original expression for the determinant (i.e., not merely for the absolute value), reported _supra_, is valid. The proof is tedious, though, and relies on the fact that the determinant is invariant to adding a multiple of one column to another. I exploited your insight, @DanielFischer, in working out this augmented proof, so that I still appreciate your input.